# Is it safe/smart to reuse your router?

Tags: vpn, router, modem

After a factory reset, would a router reuse the original Mac and IP addresses with it (even if I subnet)? I work from home and live in an apartment complex. Are there any sketchy mac tracing, spoofing, or common concerns my search missed?

I am currently moving and looking into a switch and firewall and wondering if I should just buy a new router; possibly a VPN router.

My router is a relatively new AX-WPA3.

Comment: What threat are you trying to mitigate here? What do you mean by "re-using"? What was it used for before, and what are you using it for now?

Comment: Well, I guess more of things like advertisement fingerprinting, or creepy thing like header advertisements; is a vpn router considers layer 3 like a application vpn?

Comment: What do you mean by "advertisement fingerprinting" and "header advertisements"? Are you talking about tracking used by advertising companies?

Comment: Your ISP controls your IP address.

Comment: Advertisers do not track anything having to do with your router. They track the device you use to browse.